# Run function in form (ctd)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Here's my current code and the changes I've made so far from the previous version

1. I've reset the variables at the start because I did not want them to be reset each time the function was executed
2. I've added a ess_e  variable for the entry of the procedure, I want this variable to store the localtime when the function is executed
3. I've added a ess_s variable for the exit of the procedure after all the infos are entered which should be localtime when the submit button (changed text) is pushed

The remaining problems are

1. root.bind does not work, I've tried several alternatives with fenetre as you suggested but I could not make it work.
2. I get an error when I run the 2nd function (essenceresult)

   File "D:\Bureautique\Python\Scripts\interface-test.py", line 57, in essenceResult
   ess_e = ent0.get()
   AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'get'

I still have to make the frame to display the previous results but I'll get there in due time :)

Thanks a lot for the help

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *
import time
ess=[[],[],[],[],[]]
rel=[[],[],[],[],[]]
c60=[[],[]]
def c60duree(delta):
    (h, r) = divmod(delta.seconds, 3600)
    (m, s) = divmod(r, 60)
    return "%s%02d:%02d:%02d" % (
        "%d jour(s) " % delta.days if delta.days > 0 else "",
        h,
        m,
        s,
    )
def code60():
    saisie=0
    while saisie != "X":
        c60d=datetime.now()
        print ("Code 60 activé à ", c60d.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        saisie=input("Tapez entree pour la fin du code 60, X pour sortir   : ")
        c60f=datetime.now()
        print("Debut ", c60d.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        print("Fin   ", c60f.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        c60x=c60f-c60d
        print("Duree ", c60duree(c60x))
        print("-------------")
        c60[0].append(c60d)
        c60[1].append(c60f)
#del(c60[0],[-1])
#del(c60[1],[-1])
#return

def relais():
    print("Relais pilote demarré ")
    relh=datetime.now()
    relv=input("Quelle voiture ? ")
    relp=input("Quel pilote repart ? ")
    rele=input("Quantité d'essence ? ")
    input("Tapez entrée à la sortie des stands ")
    rels=datetime.now()
    rel[0].append(relh), rel[1].append(relv), rel[2].append(relp), rel[3].append(rele), rel[4].append(rels)
    print("Dureé ", rels-relh)
    print(*rel)

#def essence():
    #ess=[[],[],[],[]]
    #print("Ravitaillement essence demarré ")
    #essh=datetime.now()
    #essv=input("Quelle voiture ? ")
    #essp=input("Quel pilote ? ")
    #essq=input("Combien de litres ? ")
    #ess[0].append(essh), ess[1].append(essv), ess[2].append(essp), ess[3].append(essq)
    #print(*ess)

def essenceResult(ess, ent0, ent1, ent2, ent3):
    ess_e = ent0.get()
    essv = ent1.get()
    essp = ent2.get()
    essq = ent3.get()
    ess_s = datetime.now()
    ess[0].append(ess_e), ess[1].append(essv), ess[2].append(essp), ess[3].append(essq), ess [4].append(ess_s)
    resultLabel = Label(Frame4, text = str(*ess))
    resultLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

def essence():
    print("yr")
    ess_e=datetime.now()
    Frame4.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    Label1 = Label(Frame4, text = "Ravitaillement demarré ")
    Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    essvLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Quelle voiture ? ")
    essvEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    essvLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    essvEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    essvEntry.focus()
    #root.bind_all("<Return>", function)
    esspLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Quel pilote part ? ")
    esspEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    esspLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    esspEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    esspEntry.focus()
    essqLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Combien de litres ? ")
    essqEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    essqLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    essqEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    essqEntry.focus()
    submitButton = Button(Frame4, text = "Sortie des stands", command = lambda: essenceResult(ess, ess_e, essvEntry, esspEntry, essqEntry))
    submitButton.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
fenetre = Tk()
fenetre['bg']='grey'

# frame 1
Frame1 = Frame(fenetre, bg="green", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5)

# frame 2
Frame2 = Frame(fenetre, bg="yellow", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx=5, pady=5)

# frame 3
Frame3 = Frame(fenetre, bg="purple", borderwidth=1, relief=GROOVE)
Frame3.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx=5, pady=5)

Frame4 = Frame(fenetre)
Fenetre = Tk()
fenetre['bg']='grey'

# Ajout de labels
Button(Frame1, text="Essence", command=essence).pack(padx=300, pady=100)
Button(Frame2, text="Relais", command=relais).pack(padx=300, pady=100)
Button(Frame3, text="Code 60", command=code60).pack(padx=300, pady=100)
```

Comment: the second error is pretty self explanatory, You can't call `.get()` on those objects (`datetime.datetime`), You apparently think they are something else when they are not, try printing what `ent0` and the others are because the error tells that they are not `Entry` widgets

Comment: also I don't see You using any `.bind` methods and why do You have two `Tk` instances? also I suggest following PEP 8 and naming variables and functions using `snake_case` while `CapitalCase` for class names (essentially no `camelCase`). Oh and also name Your variables with self-explanatory names, don't shorten them for easier typing, that won't help You

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot more code than necessary to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fixed code:

```
def essenceResult(ess, ess_e, ent1, ent2, ent3):
    essv = ent1.get()
    essp = ent2.get()
    essq = ent3.get()
    ess_s = datetime.now()
    ess[0].append(ess_e), ess[1].append(essv), ess[2].append(essp), ess[3].append(essq), ess[4].append(ess_s)
    resultLabel = Label(Frame4, text = str(ess))
    resultLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

def essence():
    print("yr")
    ess_e=datetime.now()
    Frame4.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    Label1 = Label(Frame4, text = "Ravitaillement demarré ")
    Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    essvLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Quelle voiture ? ")
    essvEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    essvLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    essvEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    essvEntry.focus()
    esspLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Quel pilote part ? ")
    esspEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    esspLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    esspEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    esspEntry.focus()
    essqLabel = Label(Frame4, text = "Combien de litres ? ")
    essqEntry = Entry(Frame4)
    essqLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    essqEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    essqEntry.focus()
    submitCommand = lambda event = None: essenceResult(ess, ess_e, essvEntry, esspEntry, essqEntry)
    submitButton = Button(Frame4, text = "Sortie des stands", command = submitCommand)
    Frame4.bind_all("<Return>", submitCommand)
    submitButton.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
```

You also need to remove the extra `Fenetre = Tk()` after `Frame4`, as this will break it. (You can only have one `Tk()`, if you want more windows use `Toplevel()`)
The first problem is solved by adding `Frame4.bind_all("<Return>", submitCommand)`. Now when you press enter it will run `submitCommand`, which will run `essenceResult`.
The second problem was using `.get()` on a `datetime.datetime` object. You can't use `.get()` because it isn't an entry. Instead, just have it as a parameter and don't change it. You only need `.get()` to get the values from a Tkinter Entry.

Comment: Ok, got some of it :)
The Frame4.bind_all("<Return>", submitCommand) still does not work because as soon as I enter the car number and press enter it validates the complete sequence and I can't enter the other values.
I thought the get() was used to receive a varaible from another function, I don't understand what the .get does with the essv nor the difference between essv and essvEntrry.
Does the ent1.get means that he's using the 2nd entry (first one being ent0) ? What is the job of the extension "Entry"  ?
FINALLY HOW DO I GO TO A NEW LINE IN THE COMMENT SECTION ??????
THANKS

Comment: .get() is a method for the tkinter Entry widget (the text box you see on screen). It gets the text from the text box, so you only need it for that. essv and essvEntry are just variable names, I used essvEntry as the variable name for one of the text boxes. Again, ent1 is just the name of a parameter of the function. It's just a name I made up. I'm not sure what you mean by new line for a comment.

Comment: ok, getting clearer and clearer :)
I need to get new lines to reply here clearer, CRLF :)
so get() gets the text from the question boxes and assigns it to the variables ? How does get know from which question box it is coming from ? In sequence ?

Comment: About the bind if I get it well what you did is to make it run "submitcommand" whenever return is pressed, right ?
 I would like it to do that when return is pressed on the submitbutton (final question) but when we are still on one of the previous question boxes i want it to give the focus to the next question box, just like what TAB is doing.
Do I need to make a bind line after each entry box and if yes what is the command for "give focus to next entry box" ?
Thanks a lot, I owe you :)

Comment: Got the bind sorted !!!

fenetre.bind('<Return>', lambda e: e.widget.event_generate('<Tab>'))

Comment: Good job :), is there anything else you need help with?

Comment: YES YES YES :)    I''ve started my save to txt file routine and it does not work as planned (of course), I'm starting a new question.